# External HDD with data to be used as bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, usb, 16.04, external-hdd, windows-10

I have an external 1TB HDD and I used that as a back up of all my data in my laptop with Windows 10. Now I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on my laptop. I already downloaded Rufus USB Installer. But can I use the same external 1TB HDD with data as the bootable USB Stick?

Answer (score 1):

You can! But, I would highly recommend against it.

1. You need to create a "Boot Partition" and that means you need a primary partition available for boot.
2. You need to move your files if your external disk is almost full or if you have to create new partitions.
3. Playing around with Disk utility is always risky, esp when you are unaware of what you do.

Instead, use an USB/Pen drive. If you're already on ubuntu, you can use the "Startup Disk creator" or if you're on Windows, try unetbootin.

Follow the instructions, viz. show the iso file, select the partition and "Burn". Once its done, insert it in your computer to be installed in and reboot. You should be on the ubuntu startup screen asking if you wanted to try or install it.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. I will try to find a USB drive. Actually I didn't have a USB drive that's the only reason why I asked this question.